# How to read the word(docx) in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
import docx

doc = docx.Document("D:\Python\wordsim\word1.docx")
```

Generate error:

> D:\Python\wordsim\venv\Scripts\python.exe D:/Python/wordsim/wordsim.py
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "D:/Python/wordsim/wordsim.py", line 1, in 
> import docx   File "D:\Python\wordsim\venv\lib\site-packages\docx.py", line 30, in
>
> from exceptions import PendingDeprecationWarning ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'exceptions'

Comment: seems like you need the module exceptions?

Comment: pip install docx2txt

Comment: I guess this other package works as well? but doesn't answer the OP

Answer (score 1):

When you install docx, use:

```
pip install python-docx
```

and not:

```
pip install docx
```

Exceptions module was removed in Python 3 and all standard exceptions were moved to builtin module.

Comment: I tried this import docx2txt
text = docx2txt.process("D:\Python\wordsim\word1.docx")
print(text)

Answer (score 0):

pip install docx2txt

After you install this using CMD, it worked for me

import docx2txt

text = docx2txt.process("D:\Python\wordsim\word1.docx")

print(text)

Answer (score 0):

Add '\\' instead of '\', your code is correct.

```
doc = docx.Document("D:\\Python\\wordsim\\word1.docx")
```

Comment: '\' this works perfectly for me. doesn't make much difference with '\\' or \ I believe